# Array input is getting one more entry than should be

Tags: c

My code isn't wrong but here's the [problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mYQN0.jpg). As you can see, the last element shouldn't appear, although it doesn't get counted it's annoying.

Here's my code:

```
int mat[3][4] = {0};
int i, j;

for(i = 0; i < 3; i++){
    for(j = 0; j < 4; j++){
        printf("insert the element [%d][%d]", i, j);
        scanf("%d ", &mat[i][j]);
    }
}

printf("\nmatrix: \n");
for(i = 0; i < 3; i++){
    for (j = 0; j < 4; j++){
        printf("%3d ", mat[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: “My code isn't wrong but…” uses a definition of “wrong” with which I am unfamiliar. If the code does not behave in the desired way, in what sense is it not wrong?

Comment: Always check the return value of `scanf()`, your code causes UB when `scanf()` fails, which isn't unlikely. I would definitely consider this code wrong (and hard to read).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check here:
You faced the problem because of white space in scanf()

*What actually happens when you ask scanf to read numeric data, it first skips any white space it finds, and then it reads characters until that character cannot form part of a number.*

```
#include <stdio.h>
    
int main()
{
    int mat[3][4] = {0};
    int i, j;

    for(i = 0; i < 3; i++){
       for(j = 0; j < 4; j++){
           printf("insert the element [%d][%d] ", i, j);
        scanf("%d", &mat[i][j]);
        }
    }

    printf("\nmatrix: \n");
    for(i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        for (j = 0; j < 4; j++){
            printf("%3d", mat[i][j]);
        }
    printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: Always check the return value of `scanf()`.